# JavaScript WIndow Print - I want it to print a specific div

Tags: javascript, printing, window

I have this nifty shopping helper at http://www.spacerock.com/shoppingplanner.php - click a meal and the ingredients appear in the shopinglist div.  I have the print window button at the top but it does not print that div.  How can I designate it to print that div?  The code for the button is  I know it's probably very simple; I'm a jQuery person and need to learn PURE JS.  Thanks in advance for your help and education.

Comment: Can you [create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (enough code to duplicate the problem) so that the code is in the question itself rather than offsite? Future visitors to this question won't be able to see the problem after you fix it on that site.

Answer (score 1):

**Use This JS:**
to print specific `DIV` with `ID='content'`

```
<input style="width:75px" type="button" name="printreport" id="printreport" value="Print List" onclick="printpage()">

function printpage()
    {
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printReport = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printReport;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [printThis](https://rawgit.com/jasonday/printThis/master/printThis.js)  Jquery plugin:

```
$('SelectorToPrint').printThis();
```

**JSFIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/df4tzcq5/

Comment: I went ahead and put the plugin into place and changed up the code for the button, giving it an id as printBtn and wrote this:  $('#printBtn').click(function(){
    $('#shoppinglist').printElement();
});  However, it does not work.  I get an error that printElement is not a function.

Comment: @MarianStevens I could not get it to work either. I found another one called printThis() by Jason Day that works. See JSFiddle in the answer.

Comment: That didn't do it either; I'm using ajax to populate my div and it won't print the content that I am populating it with.  I checked your fiddle too and didn't see the heading you were adding at all.